# Differential operator and equivalence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

Here is the problem:
I have a certain PDE and there is the nonlinear terme $h$, I have as data:
$f \in H_0^2(0,L)$,,,$g \in {H^1}(0,L)$ with ${g_x}(0) = {g_x}(L) = 0$
Now on consider the fnction  $$h(x) = f'(x)(g'(x) + {(f'(x))^2}){\rm{ }}{\rm{, x}} \in {\rm{[0}}{\rm{,L]}}$$
we notice that $h(0)=h(L)=0$.
It is well known that the operator:$$(I - \partial {}_x^2):H_0^1(0,L) \cap {H^2}(0,L) \to {L^2}(0,L)$$ is bounded and invertible, and its inverse defined by:
$${(I - \partial {}_x^2)^{ - 1}}:{L^2}(0,L) \to H_0^1(0,L) \cap {H^2}(0,L)$$
the question: have we the inequality $${\left\| {{\partial _x}{{(I - \partial {}_x^2)}^{ - 1}}{\partial _x}h} \right\|_{{L^2}(0,L)}} \le c{\left\| h \right\|_{{L^2}(0,L)}}??$$ ($c$ is a positive constant) 
and if this is wrong, what conditions can I pose on $f$ and $g$ to satisfy this inequality..? and if this is true, how can I prove it rigorously?

Comment: Make a Fourier transform, the opetator $\partial_x$ becomes the operator $f(t)\to it\cdot f(t)$, and your operator becomes a multiplication by $t^2/(1+t^2)$, which is of course bounded.

Comment: Hello sir ....in our case we have a finite intervalle not R...How can we make the Fourier transform...?

Comment: We may extend the functions to the whole line (by zero values outside the interval), but at moment I doubt that the inverse of $I-\partial_x^2$ is the same as making Fourier transform, multiplying by $1/(1+t^2)$ and taking inverse Fourier transform...

Comment: Thanks...so the inequality is true....how can I use the conditions $h(0)=h(L)=0$ ? Can I work without them ? Thanks. there is a second question in my mind: Can I prove the inequality using spectral decomposition ? thanks.

Comment: Forget this Fourier approach. The operator $A=i\partial_x$ is self-adjoint, thus $A^2(I+A^2)^{-1}$ has norm at most 1 by spectral decomposition.

Comment: Are the two operator are equal? $${{\partial _x}{{(I - \partial {}_x^2)}^{ - 1}}{\partial _x}}$$  and $${{\partial ^2}_x{{(I - \partial {}_x^2)}^{ - 1}}}$$ ?

Comment: All functions of the same operator commute

Comment: Excuse me sir...Can you explain more? if you have some references whio talk about that  and the norme if this operator I will be grateful...thanks